# FPeval in a macro

Tags: macros, fp

I am writing a document where I need to use a lot the following construct

```
\FPeval{\born}{1833}
\FPeval{\died}{1894}
\FPeval{\age}{round(\died - \born,0)}

Born in \born, died in \died (\age years old)
```

I thought of writing a macro so I can write `\lifespan{1833}{1894}` and save me from pasting. I tried to write the obvious:

```
\newcommand{\lifespan}[2]{
\FPeval{\born}{#1}
\FPeval{\died}{#2}
\FPeval{\age}{round(\died - \born,0)}

Born in \born, died in \died (\age years old)
}
```

But it tells me that `\lifespan` is undefined. Is there any way to do this or am I just wasting my time? Is there any way to write a macro C style? Something that tells latex to substitute some text before it starts compiling the document?

Comment: What exactly did you do, `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fp} \newcommand{\lifespan}[2]{ \FPeval{\born}{#1} \FPeval{\died}{#2} 
 \FPeval{\age}{round(\died - \born,0)}  Born in \born, died in \died (\age years old) }  \begin{document} \lifespan{1900}{1945} \end{document}` works fine.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your `\lifespan` macro. However, you might be interested in `\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand{\lifespan}[2]{Born in #1, died in #2 (\fpeval{#2-#1} years old)}`.

Comment: You're a member for more than two years and do not post a MWE (or MNWE), but only fragments :-(

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I didn't post a MNWE, I spent too much time on it and it was late... Today it works, I have no idea what I have changed, but definitely it was not the macro (I copy pasted). I guess I changed something else as I was trying so solve it.

Comment: I kind of hate Tex that works sometimes in semi-random ways and it is so hard to track errors

Comment: I'm voting to close this as being unclear - there is no indication why the current code doesn't work, nor why it magically worked later. No MWE also makes for the problem to be not reproducible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to use such a big gun as `fp` for simple arithmetic with integers:

```
\newcommand{\lifespan}[2]{%
  Born in~#1, died in~#2 (%
  {\count255=#2\relax
  \advance\count255 by -#1\relax
  \the\count255\relax}%
  ~years old)%
}
```

Arithmetic in TeX is not like in C.

If you prefer a different syntax, use friendlier tools than `fp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lifespan}{mm}{%
  Born in~#1, died in~#2 (\inteval{#2-#1}~years old)%
}

\begin{document}

\lifespan{1879}{1955}

\end{document}
```

---

By the way, your code runs flawlessly (although you're inserting several unwanted spaces and a new paragraph).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand{\lifespan}[2]{
\FPeval{\born}{#1}
\FPeval{\died}{#2}
\FPeval{\age}{round(\died - \born,0)}

Born in \born, died in \died (\age years old)
}

\begin{document}

\lifespan{1833}{1894}

\end{document}
```

This document compiles with no error.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tst.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))
No file tst.aux.
( FP-EVAL ( FP-UPN ) ) ( FP-EVAL ( FP-UPN ) ) ( FP-EVAL ( FP-UPN ( FP-SUB )
( FP-ROUND ) ) ) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/p
dftex.map}] (./tst.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on tst.pdf (1 page, 14096 bytes).
Transcript written on tst.log.
```

A better version would be

```
\newcommand{\lifespan}[2]{%
  \FPeval{\born}{#1}%
  \FPeval{\died}{#2}%
  \FPeval{\age}{round(\died - \born,0)}%
  Born in \born, died in \died\ (\age\ years old)%
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What bugs me is that you can't really tell the age of a person based only on years when he was born and deceased. You calculations might be off by one year. So, I'd suggest you to use the full dates and do the calculations based on that. The following code might be a bit overcomplicated in order to use simple `\lifespan` syntax. It parses the dates first, and then computes the lifespan using the @egreg's excellent suggestion on `xfp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp,etoolbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitdate}{mmmu{-}u{-}u{\relax}}{%
  \def#1{#4}%
  \def#2{#5}%
  \def#3{#6}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lifespan}{mm}{%
  \splitdate\byear\bmonth\bday#1\relax
  \splitdate\dyear\dmonth\dday#2\relax
  \def\diff{0}%
  \ifnumcomp{\bmonth}{>}{\dmonth}{%
    \def\diff{1}%
  }{%
    \ifnumcomp{\bmonth}{=}{\dmonth}{%
      \ifnumcomp{\bday}{>}{\dday}{%
        \def\diff{1}%
      }{}%
    }{}}%
  Born in~\byear, died in~\dyear\ (\inteval{\dyear-\byear-\diff}~years old)%
}

\begin{document}
\lifespan{1799-05-26}{1837-01-29}

\lifespan{1828-08-28}{1910-11-07}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Wow! I am impressed! I decided that this is too complicated and I didn't mind having this error a lot, so I didn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\lifespan[2]{%
    Born in #1, died in #2 (\directlua{tex.sprint(#2-#1)} years old).}

\begin{document}
\lifespan{1833}{1894}

\lifespan{1900}{1990}
\end{document}
```